# Does R's parallel foreach save objects for additional iterations within the same child operation?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, parallel-foreach

I am running a process in parallel using the doParallel/Foreach backend in R.  I'm registering a set of 20 cores as a cluster, and running the process about 100 times.  I'm passing a matrix to each iteration of the parallel processes, and in the sub-process I replace the matrix with a random sample of its own rows.  What I'm wondering is: should I expect that this modification persists for subsequent iterations handled by the same child process?  E.g., when child process 1 finishes its first iteration, does it start the second iteration with the original matrix, or the random sample?

A minimal example:

```
   library(doParallel)

   X <- matrix(1:400, ncol=4)

   cl<-makeCluster(2)
   clusterExport(X)
   registerDoParallel(cl)


   results<-foreach(i=1:100) %dopar% {
       set.seed(12345)
       X <- X[sample.int(nrow(X),replace=TRUE),]
       X
   }
```

**EDIT:**

To be clear, if indeed the object will persist across iterations by the same worker process, this is not my desired behavior.  Rather, I want to have each iteration take a fresh random sample of the original matrix, not a random sample of the most recent random sample (I recognize that in my minimal example it would moreover create the *same* random sample of the original matrix each time, due to the seed set--in my actual application I deal with this).

Answer (score 1):

Side effects within a cluster worker that persistent across iterations of a foreach loop are possible, but that is not a supported feature of foreach. Programs that take advantage of it probably won't be portable to different parallel backends, and may not work with newer versions of the software. In fact, I tried to make that kind of side effect impossible when I first wrote foreach, but I eventually gave up.

Note that in your case, you're not modifying the copy of `X` that was explicitly exported to the workers: you're modifying a copy that was auto-exported to the workers by doParallel. That has probably been a source of confusion to you.

If you really want to do this, I suggest that you turn off auto-exporting of `X` and then modify the explicitly exported copy so that the program should be well defined and portable, although a bit ugly. Here's an example:

```
library(doParallel)
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(2)
registerDoParallel(cl)
X <- matrix(0, nrow=4, ncol=4)
clusterExport(cl, 'X')
ignore <- clusterApply(cl, seq_along(cl), function(i) ID <<- i)
results <-
  foreach(i=1:4, .noexport='X') %dopar% {
    X[i,] <<- ID
    X
  }
finalresults <- clusterEvalQ(cl, X)
```

`results` contains the matrices after each task, and `finalresults` contain the matrices on each of the workers after the foreach loop has completed.

---

*Update*

In general, the body of the foreach loop shouldn't modify any variable that is outside of the foreach loop. I only modify variables that I created previously in the same iteration of the foreach loop. If you want to make a modified version that is only used within that iteration, use a different variable name.

Comment: To be clear, I *don't* want to have the object modified each time.  Rather, I was afraid this may be happening without my meaning to, leading to errors.  My question wasn't very clear on this point; I'll fix it.